# How do you change the color of the line that Text is drawn on?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

In Illustrator I used the `Type on path` tool and typed a word on a black drawn line.

I have change the style of the brush the line is using and now I want to change the color of the line. 
The text and the line seem to have been merged into a single object and when I change the color of the selected object, only the font color changes, the line does not change.

If I move the text, the line moves with it. 
They seem to be one object but the text paints separately from the line.

How do I paint the line?

I have replicated the results in the screenshot below.

**Top picture:**
Created text on a line. Changed the brush stroke of the text, which added the effect visible in the bottom.

**Bottom picture:**
Changed the color of the stroke, which only edits the font stroke, not the brush that is now visible.
[image]

Comment: Please, place a screenshot of an area

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When converting a path to a text-path, the fill and stroke of the path is automatically changed to `None`, but you can re-assign colors to the path that are independent of the fill/stroke applied to the text.
The trick is to select the path portion of the object using the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow). [image: Direct Selection Tool]

---

Here's how to tell which you have selected:

### Text Selected

[image: Type Selected]
You can tell the text is selected because of the text edge and center markers on the path (red arrows), and in the **Appearance** panel, it shows **Type** (green box).
Note that the actual path has no fill, but the **Color** panel matches the fill/stroke applied to the text.

### Path Selected

[image: Path Selected]
You can tell the path is selected because there are no text markers, and the **Appearance** panel shows **Path** (green box).
Note that in the **Color** panel fill/stroke definitions now apply to the path only, not the text.
Although it isn't necessary for this, if you hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while using the **Direct Selection Tool**, you select the entire object. This is useful when trying to pick one object within a group.

Comment: Nicely explained. There is *no* reason one needs to "duplicate" a text path to apply a stroke or fill to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it just became a part of the text, so if you want to have the line there, you have to duplicate the line before you are using the type on path tool.

Hope this'll help you some kind.

Comment: well the line is there and visible... its black.

Answer (score 0):

When you place text on a path, the path automatically becomes hidden. If you want to see it, then duplicate it first and place the text on the copy.

Are you sure the path is really visible? Or is it showing up only when the text is selected?

Comment: I've updated my results with screenshots to show how I did what I did to get the line to be visible. This may be poor technique I'm new to illustrator.